# Embedded Jetty H2 JNDI Datasouce - javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name

Tags: datasource, jndi, h2, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to setup a JNDI datasource for H2 database using Jetty Web Server; I have un-commented plus config in start.ini of Jetty and also added Configurations to jetty.xml as per Jetty documentation and created a jetty-web.xml which configures datasource to an existing WebAppContext. When I try to get datasource using intialcontext.lookup() all I get is a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env/jdbc/MyH2DS'
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:117)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.tutorial.DbConnector.<init>(DbConnector.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:99)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:158)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:59)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:64)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.LabelRenderer.encodeBegin(LabelRenderer.java:121)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1017)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Jun 05, 2013 4:23:47 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/welcome.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /welcome.xhtml @13,86 value="Selected From DataSource: #{dbConnector.dsConnection}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.LabelRenderer.encodeBegin(LabelRenderer.java:121)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1017)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tutorial.DbConnector.getDsConnection(DbConnector.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:59)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:64)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 34 more

2013-06-05 16:23:47.496:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp24549422-11: 
javax.servlet.ServletException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1017)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tutorial.DbConnector.getDsConnection(DbConnector.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:59)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:64)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.LabelRenderer.encodeBegin(LabelRenderer.java:121)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:681)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1017)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**jetty-web.xml :**

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext" id="wac">
        <Arg>jdbc/MyH2DS</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource">
                <Set name="URL">jdbc:h2:/test</Set>
                <Set name="user">sa</Set>
                <Set name="password"></Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
</Configure>
```

**Server code :**

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
        WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext();
        File warPath = new File("C:/Users/XCB638.DS/workspace/MyJSFProject/WebContent/WEB-INF");
        wac.setWar(warPath.getAbsolutePath());
        wac.setContextPath("/");
        wac.setBaseResource(new ResourceCollection(new String[] { "./WebContent", "build/classes" }));
        server.setHandler(wac);
        try
        {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Have you configured web.xml pointing to jetty-web.xml?

Have you defined </new> element with an id to be  pointed at we.xml?